CB style PTT Mics to USB circuit
I need to design a circuit that takes the input from 2 different CB style (4-pin) push-to-talk microphones and pipes them out to USB.  CB mics I have confirmed use regular XLR balanced level output.  The 4th pin is for the trigger button.  I don't have much experience with audio circuit design, so I was hoping for a little guidance on what I need to set this up.  I presume I need some sort of pre-amp for the mics, an Analog-to-Digital IC, and a USB interface IC.  I really need it all to run on USB power as well.  Does anyone have any advice or examples?

Can you add a link to the type of microphone you're talking about, because what I would call a 'CB Mic' doesn't fit your description at all. Are you talking about CB radio? If so what country? I'm familiar with CB radio mics in the U.S., they don't used balanced audio here, a 4 pin mic would have common, audio, TX and RX.

Yes, US CB radio type microphone. I might be wrong on the XLR, but the write-ups specify that.  I just assumed all XLR's were balanced.  Like I said, not a lot of experience with audio circuits.  Here's a link to the manual for the Mic I was looking at:  https://www.bobscb.com/PDGManuals/AST-636LDX1-B.pdf  I thought maybe the TI INA1651 would be good for processing the mic signal.

@mucle-nerd-jerry Ok, that's going to be a dynamic microphone, basically it's like a speaker in reverse, a coil and magnet, movement of the coil generates a voltage. In a typical CB setup the white wire would be audio (connects directly to the mic element), the shield and blue would be connected together as common, red would be TX, black would be RX. Inside the CB the RX pin connects to the speaker (-), so when the mic is unkeyed the speaker is grounded through the blue wire, when keyed it opens this connection disconnecting the speaker so you don't get feedback.

@GodJihyo Thanks for the info!  Now I've got to get all of that piped through to USB so it can be input into a PC. What would be the next link in the chain?

@MuscleNerdJerry Do you must design something yourself or just buy a $2 USB sound card?

The PC needs to get an indication when that PTT button is pressed so it can interrupt all other audio and switch to the mic input.  I have yet to find anything that can accomplish this; that's why I'm looking to design this circuit.  Think of it as a PA (Public Address) USB module.

Anyone one else want to take a stab at it?

You can buy a ready to use USB audio interface, for example SoundBlaster Play 3. It's quite costly (about USD20), but numerous much lower cost (and lower quality) options exist. Get one to test. The headphone or audio line output is included.
When held near talker's mouth, the dynamic mic of your CB-mic apparel outputs maybe 100 millivolts AC, so it doesn't need anything special. You can always attenuate the signal with a voltage divider, if your mic is too sensitive. The possible low voltage DC bias through a several kilo-ohm resistor for electret mic is not harmful to your mic. In low cost devices it may be ON permanently without a possibility to turn it OFF in the software.
It's up to you what you are going to do with the talk switch. The audio interface is interested only in the audio signal. Reading the state of the switch needs different computer input.
Making your system to do something useful you need also proper computer program which delivers the needed functionality.

You must provide proper attribution to the picture. Also most such adapters are intended for electret capsule mics, not dynamic mics, so the output of dynamic mic may be too loud.

The software doesn't concern me at the moment.  That'll be another project in and of itself.  For the hardware, pre-made  Audio-to-USB solutions lack the the ability to sense the PTT trigger.  So that's why I'm looking to design this circuit.

@MuscleNerdJerry The sheer complexity of computer USB audio probably forces you to use a somehow standard compliant interface IC. There are some USB<-->  Digital audio bridges which have also inputs that you can use to read the talk switch state. They do not contain the AD converter for the mic but accept a digital audio stream. Then there are IC:s which have only audio in and out + USB interface for connecting the IC to a computer. You can send the state of the switch as a pilot tone which is detected &removed in the application software. That works also with a purchased USB audio interface.
